# How should I update Xcode when I installed it from the app store but it hasn't updated to most recent version?

Tags: macos, ios, xcode, big-sur

I have OS X version 11.0.1 (Big Sur), and checked to see if my Xcode were up to date. I originally installed Xcode from the app store because I'd read that if you do it that way, it updates automatically. When I checked, the Xcode version was 11.3.1, and when I looked at [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) in the `Xcode 11.x - 12.x (since SwiftUI framework)` table, it seems like the Xcode version should have automatically updated to 12.1.1.

**What I Want To Know:**

I read that if you download Xcode from the app store, it updates automatically, whereas if you download it from `developer.apple.com/download`, it doesn't. Given that it doesn't seem to have updated itself after downloading from the app store, should I download version 12.1.1 from `developer.apple.com/download`? If so, will it continue to not update itself, and I should plan to update it manually from now on? Or do you have any other advice on how I should handle this?

Answer (score 3):

Xcode is not automatically updated as a consequence of updating to Big Sur.

Just installing Xcode from the App Store itself won't automatically ensure it is updated. This only happens if you have enabled automatic updates in the Mac App Store settings.

In any case, there can be a lag from the time the new version is released and until the automatic update feature on your Mac notices it and upgrades.

You can always just open the App Store, go to the page for Xcode and hit the "Update" button there.

If you download and install Xcode manually from a link, then no, it will not automatically update from that point on.